# Convert Polynomial to Sum

Tags: polynomials, recursive-algorithms

I have to convert the polynomial: $P_4=x^4+7x^3-13x^2-103x-84$ into the form: $$P_4(x)=\sum_{i=0}^4 a_i(x-1)^i$$ using Horner's Method.

I can evaluate both of them using Horner's Method, but I can't figure out how to convert them into one another.

Comment: The second representation is the (finite) Taylor expansion about $x=1$ so you can find the coefficients by evaluating the derivatives of $P$ at $1$.

Comment: I did figure that out through some thorough searching, but I didn't understand any of the descriptions on how exactly to perform it.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative answer, using nothing but high-school algebra.

I'm going to express $x^3 + 3x^1 - x + 4$ in powers of $x-1$. Why *this* polynomial? So that *you* can do the work with the real one.

But why THIS one? I grabbed the coefficients randomly from thin air (keeping them fairly small to make the arithmetic not so bad). It turns out to work out reasonably well, but that was just blind luck, I promise.

Let's go one degree at a time. 
$$
x^3 + 3x^2 -x + 4 = A(x-1)^3 + \text{lower order terms}.
$$
Now $(x-1)^3 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1$, so $A$ times that is going to start with $Ax^3$...but we want $1 \cdot x^3$. So we have to pick $A = 1$. I'm going to write "LOT" for "lower order terms" from now on. Anyhow, we now know that $A$ has to be $1$, and we get
\begin{align}
x^3 + 3x^2 -x + 4 &= 1(x-1)^3 + LOT \\
x^3 + 3x^2 -x + 4 &= x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 + LOT \\
x^3 + 3x^2 -x + 4 - (x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1) &=  LOT \\
 6x^2 -4x + 5  &=  LOT \\
\end{align}
and look! Now we have to write a *quadratic* in terms of powers of $(x-1)$. The first of those is going to be some multiple of $(x-1)^2$, so let's go!
\begin{align}
 6x^2 -4x + 5  &=  B(x-1)^2 + LOT \\
\end{align}
Now you can see that because $(x-1)^2 = x^2 -2x + 1$, that $B$ must be $6$. So write
\begin{align}
 6x^2 -4x + 5  &=  6(x-1)^2 + LOT \\
 6x^2 -4x + 5  &=  6(x^2-2x+1) + LOT \\
 6x^2 -4x + 5  &=  6x^2-12x+6 + LOT \\
  8x -1   &=  LOT \\
\end{align}

Now $8x-1$ is supposed to be a sum of powers of $(x-1)$, and it's clear the first of these is $C(x-1)$, and you can guess by now that $C = 8$. We get
\begin{align}
  8x -1   &=  8(x-1) + LOT \\
  8x -1   &=  8x-8 + LOT \\
   7   &=   LOT \\
\end{align}

and the final low-order term is $7(x-1)^0$. So we've got $A = 1, B = 6, C = 8, D = 7$, hence
$$
x^3 + 3x^2 -x + 4 = 1(x-1)^3 + 6(x-1)^2 + 8(x-1) + 7,
$$
assuming I did all the algebra correctly. Yay!

Now, can you repeat that process for your quartic?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I believe this is how they wanted me to do it.
My answers are: $a_4=1, a_3=11, a_2=14, a_1=-104, a_0=-192$


I checked them, and they check out!

Comment: I personally worry that this is NOT how they wanted you to do it, because I never mentioned Horner's rule (which I can never remember). But who knows? Anyhow, it's *one* way of doing it, which is I guess a good thing.

Comment: If you can read my notes, this is how they did it in the example, but I can't make heads nor tails of it. I copied them exactly. Page 1: https://i.imgur.com/wkYsXqg.jpg
Page 2: https://i.imgur.com/Em110GK.jpg

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{P^{(i)}(1)}{i!}(x-1)^i
$$

The best way to prove this identity (in general) is to use a little calculus. (Strictly speaking that's not necessary - there are finite difference arguments that don't call for the full machinery.)

For your particular example, 
$$
P(1) = 1 + 7 -13 -103 - 84 = -192
$$
$$
P'(x) = 4x^3 + 21x^2 -26x - 103 
$$
$$
P'(1) = 4 + 21 -26 -103 = -104
$$
$$
P"(x) = P^{(2)}(x)= 12x^2 + 42x -26
$$
$$
P"(1) = P^{(2)}(1) = 12  + 42  -26 = 28
$$
$$
P^{(3)}(x) = 24x  + 42 
$$
$$
P^{(3)}(1) = 24  + 42 = 66
$$
$$
P^{(4)}(x) = 24  = P^{(4)}(1)
$$
so

$$
P(x) = -192 - 104(x-1) + \frac{28}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{66}{3 \cdot 2}(x-1)^3 + 
\frac{24}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}(x-1)^4
$$
(if I haven't made any arithmetic errors).  The fact that the coefficients come out integers, as they must, is a preliminary check. You can verify for sure by multiplying it out.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I need at least 1 example to understand this. I just cannot see it. Also, where does this $x=1$ come from, and the $i!$?

Comment: @Brendan I've worked out the algebra and the arithmetic for your example. $i!$ is "$i$ factorial", which is $i(i-1)(i-2)\cdots 2 \cdot 1$. The $x=1$ comes from the fact that you want powers of $x-1$ in your new expansion. For reasons that go deeper you need to learn more math than I can provide here - calculus or the algebra of finite differences.

Comment: Thanks! We weren't allowed to use derivatives yet, but this is a nice and simple way to solve the problem. I'll definitely remember this!
BTW, Your $P^3$ is wrong in the last line.

Comment: You're welcome. Fixed the $66$ thanks - you could edited that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Write $t=x-1$ and then calculate $$P_4(t+1)=(t+1)^4+7(t+1)^3-13(t+1)^2-103(t+1)-84$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2+a_3(x-1)^3+a_4(x-1)^4=x^4+7x^3-13x^2-103x-84 \stackrel{x=1}{\Rightarrow} \\
\color{red}{a_0}=1+7-13-103-84=\color{red}{-192};\\
(x-1)[a_1+a_2(x-1)+a_3(x-1)^2+a_4(x-1)^3]=x^4+7x^3-13x^2-103x+108 \stackrel{\div (x-1)}{\Rightarrow} \\
a_1+a_2(x-1)+a_3(x-1)^2+a_4(x-1)^3=x^3+8x^2-5x-108 \stackrel{x=1}{\Rightarrow} \\
\color{red}{a_1}=1+8-5-108=\color{red}{-104};\\
(x-1)[a_2+a_3(x-1)+a_4(x-1)^2]=x^3+8x^2-5x-4 \stackrel{\div (x-1)}{\Rightarrow} \\
a_2+a_3(x-1)+a_4(x-1)=x^2+9x+4 \stackrel{x=1}{\Rightarrow} \\
\color{red}{a_2}=1+9+4=\color{red}{14};\\
\vdots$$
Can you continue and finish?